# Using php code on html page using htaccess file

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, server

I am on a shared linux server using php7. I want my .html pages use php. I have tried every answer on here, things so far are;

`AddType application/x-httpd-php7.0 .html .htm`  -  downloads the page when trying to open it

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-imh-php70 .html` - does nothing

Comment: Try `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm`

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this in .htaccess, worked for me:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.(htm|html)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

https:/www.example.com/test/my.html or my.htm will be interpreted by php7.